# How to add infoBox & sparkline plot to the column in fluidrow in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and trying to add `lineplots` under each `infobox` as shown in image below. But **Issue** is that I am **unable** to **add** any more items **(infobox + lineplots)** to this row.

[image]

**Code:**

```
 
    fluidRow(
        
    
        column(2, selectInput(inputId = "id_country_timeline", label = "Select Country (applies on this page)", 
                              choices = unique(ts_all_long$Country.Region), selected = "India")),
        
        column(1, 
               infoBoxOutput("daily_confrm", width = NULL),
               plotOutput("ConfirmDaily_line_only", height = "40px", width = 80)),
        column(1,
               infoBoxOutput("daily_death", width = NULL),
               plotOutput("DeathDaily_line_only", height = "40px", width = 80)),
        column(1,
               infoBoxOutput("tot_confrm", width = NULL),
               plotOutput("Confirm_line_only", height = "40px", width = 80)),
        column(1,
               infoBoxOutput("tot_death", width = NULL),
               plotOutput("Death_line_only", height = "40px", width = 80))
        ,
        # column(1,
        #        infoBoxOutput("tot_death", width = NULL),
        #        plotOutput("Death_line_only", height = "40px", width = 80))
        # ,
        # column(2,
        #        infoBoxOutput("per_vaccinated", width = NULL),
        #        plotOutput("Death_line_only", height = "40px", width = 80)
        #        ),
        # div(style = "height:80px;")
        
    ),
```

When I **uncomment** even the next column containing `infobox & plotoutput` then the whole page goes **blank**. I guess the fluid row can have 12 item column which I have not fully utilized but is there a limit to how many items can be added to the row ??

And when I increase the column size from 1 to 2 then they do spread over the entire row.

[image]

I am not sure why I am unable to add any more such items to it.

Answer (score 0):

Was having issues because I was using same `id` multiple times. If `ids` are used once or they are unique then they seems to work well.